# gtid_binlog_pos variable contains two values

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am trying to setup a master-slave replication with galera-cluster (choose 1 node as the primary master) and a standalone mariadb server (slave).

I have successfully setup the replication and data is in sync.

However, when I check the `gtid_binlog_pos` from the slave node, it is showing `0-1-2` (primary master's binlog pos) and `99-2-2` (slave itself's binlog pos).

Is this normal and what does it mean?

```
MariaDB [testdb]> show variables like 'gtid%';
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name           | Value        |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| gtid_binlog_pos         | 0-1-2,99-2-2 |
| gtid_binlog_state       | 0-1-2,99-2-2 |
| gtid_cleanup_batch_size | 64           |
| gtid_current_pos        | 0-1-2,99-2-2 |
| gtid_domain_id          | 99           |
| gtid_ignore_duplicates  | OFF          |
| gtid_pos_auto_engines   |              |
| gtid_seq_no             | 0            |
| gtid_slave_pos          | 0-1-2        |
| gtid_strict_mode        | OFF          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

And here is my configuration files:
primary master `/etc/my.cnf.d/replication.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
# Galera node as master
wsrep_gtid_mode      = on
wsrep_gtid_domain_id = 0

server-id          = 01
log_slave_updates  = on
relay-log-index    = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb01-relay-bin.index
relay-log          = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb01-relay-bin
gtid_domain_id     = 1
log-bin            = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb01-bin
log-bin-index      = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb01-bin.index
binlog_format      = ROW
log_error          = /var/log/mysql/mariadb.err

replicate-do-db    = testdb
```

slave `/etc/my.cnf.d/replication.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
#Replication slave to Galera Cluster
server-id          = 02
log_slave_updates  = on
relay-log-index    = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb03-relay-bin.index
relay-log          = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb03-relay-bin
gtid_domain_id     = 99
log-bin            = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb03-bin
log-bin-index      = /var/log/mysql/gmariadb03-bin.index
binlog_format      = ROW
log_error          = /var/log/mysql/mariadb.err

replicate-do-db    = testdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks correct for your configuration.

From the MariaDB [GTID documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/gtid/):

> A global transaction ID, or GTID for short, consists of three numbers
> separated with dashes '-'. For example:
>
> 0-1-10
>
> - The first number 0 is the domain ID, which is specific for global transaction ID (more on this below). It is a 32-bit unsigned integer.
> - The second number is the server ID, the same as is also used in old-style replication. It is a 32-bit unsigned integer.
> - The third number is the sequence number. This is a 64-bit unsigned integer that is monotonically increasing for each new event group
>   logged into the binlog.
>
> The server ID is set to the server ID of the server where the event
> group is first logged into the binlog. The sequence number is
> increased on a server for every event group logged. Since server IDs
> must be unique for every server, this makes the (server_id,
> sequence_number) pair, and hence the whole GTID, globally unique.